# Java while loop confusing output

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The output prints out 4 2. I understand why "y" is 4 but I'm confused why "z" is 2. 
Shouldn't ++ increment the value of "z" by one?

```
int x = 6;
int y = 1;
int z = 0;

while (2 * y <= x) {
    y = y * 2;
    z++;
}
System.out.println(y + " " + z);
```

Comment: while loop will execute two times

Comment: `++` is not a one time thing. `z` starts with 0 an then it is incremented by 1 2 times.

Comment: What did you expect `z` to be?

Comment: A simple printout within the loop will make it  clear

Comment: When it executes the second time, isn't 8 <= 6 false? So why would it execute the statement and increment 1 to the value of z?

Comment: The first time y = 1 so 2 * 1 = 2 which is less than 6, so y is then multiplied by 2, and when y = 2, 2 * 2 = 4 which is still less than 6 so it will execute the inner loop again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help, I was over thinking it.
The mistake I kept making was taking the value of "y" from the condition and using it on the statement. 
In other words, instead of starting out with y = 1 * 2; , I would start out with the second iteration of y = 2 * 2; and think that the value of "z" was 1 and that the loop ended there.
Thank you c0der for the suggestion of the printout within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In first iteration y is 1 so `2*y <= x` satisfy. And `y = y*2` which is 2 and z becomes 1.
Again `2*y<=x` satisfy because `2*y` is 4 and `y= y*2` becomes 8 and `z++` becomes 2.
Resulting output 4 and 2

Answer (score -2):

I don't see any errors in the program. The loop will run 2 times:

Firstly, `z` will be `0+1=1`, after that it will be `1+1=2`.

`2*Y` becomes `8` which doesn't satisfy the condition, so the final output should be that `Y` is `4` and `Z` is `2`.

Comment: Y WILL NEVER BECOME 8 IT'S VALUES WILL BE 4

Comment: Sry I mean 2*y will be 8